# Keeping FileSystemDirectoryHandle object in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, file-system-access-api

I'm working on Chrome extension. Inside popup I can run `window.showDirectoryPicker()`, which  returns object of type `FileSystemDirectoryHandle`.

My problem is that after changing tab in browser popup is automatically closed, so object is destroyed.

My question is: is there any way to pass this object to any other context (for example to ServiceWorker or other window)?

Or if it is not possible, is there any way for invoking window.showDirectoryPicker() inside extension's ServiceWorker?

Answer (score 2):

- Send the handle via the standard service worker messaging from an extension page:

  ```js
  (async () => {
    const handle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
    const swr = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    swr.active.postMessage(handle);
  })();
  ```

  In the service worker, use `self.onmessage = e => { console.log(e) };`
  Note that it'll print in the background devtools.
- Copy from one extension page to another extension page that is currently open via [getViews](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getViews):

  ```js
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'another.html'}, async tab => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function onUpdated(tabId) {
        if (tabId === tab.id) {
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
    const wnd = chrome.extension.getViews({tabId: tab.id})[0];
    wnd._handle = handle;
    // `another` page will see a global variable `window._handle`
  });
  ```
- Send via [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel/BroadcastChannel) within the extension pages or the service worker.
- Save it in [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and reuse it in the future.